# Is there a Money class for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, currency

*Disclaimer: complete rewrite for clarity as of 10/14/2011*

**Given** the `number` primitive in JavaScript is an [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) 64-bit floating point (*known in other languages as a double*), and [using floats to model currencies is a **bad idea**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency), **is a Money prototype** (JavaScript) **or a [Coffeescript Class](http://rzrsharp.net/2011/06/21/classes-in-coffeescript.html)** that eases use of pseudo-integer cents and string [currency ISO 4217 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) to represent currency **available**?

^ There's still gotta be a better way to say that.

I'm hoping to find something that mirrors the common design pattern of the many other languages out there that do include an integer primitive.

As examples, I'm familiar with the [money gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/money) for ruby, and the [python-money](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-money/0.5) package, both of which implement variations of this design pattern.

Ideally looking for something that will play nice with [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) and [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), but all suggestions appreciated.

*Edit 4*: As far as I can tell, as long as an implementation of `roundDownOrUp ? floor : ceiling` is called on the Number after every operation (& in between chained operations) everything would function as if one were dealing with integers.

---

#### Old information, retained to document the history of the question.

I read [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)
where I found [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/) and [jQuery Globalize](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/39118647/Globalize) which both do pretty printing but are not designed to model currencies and perform operations with them.

*Edit 1*: Just found [JSorm Currency](http://jsorm.com/wiki/Currency) in the [npm registry](http://search.npmjs.org/#/jsorm-i18n) which is ISO 4217 aware, but does not appear to include any fixes for float "*gotchas*". Please correct if I have misread.

*Edit 2 folded into rewrite.*

*Edit 3*: It looks like a good option would be to use [node-bigint](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint) as suggested by @RicardoTomasi.

Comment: If not, you can always build one. `:D`

Comment: If not, I most certainly intend to ;)

Comment: Just make sure and release it for others. I imagine somewhere someone has done this (in the finance or trading industry), but it's probably proprietary.

Comment: As soon as you talk about accounting systems, you need to accommodate different rules for different situations (e.g. rounding). I imagine money functions are pretty simple unless you want to deal with pre-decimal pounds or similar non-decimal systems.

Comment: @RobG - `.convertToUS()` solves that... `:P :P :P`

Comment: @JaredFarrish - depends on the exchange rate, administration in power, your country of domicile (not all friends of the US are created equal)... :-)

Comment: @RobG - That was a poor attempt at humor. It must have been non-convertible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both [bigdecimal.js](https://github.com/jhs/bigdecimal.js/) and [node-bigint](https://github.com/substack/node-bigint) have arbitrary precision.

I'd go with bigint. bigdecimal is a GWT version of of Java's BigDecimal, clocking in at 113kb, so the code is not what one would call *readable*.

**update:** [money.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.com/money.js/) has just been released, but it uses javascript's native Number, and is focused on currency conversion.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using javascript's native Number?

Comment: @Mitja precision. For example in JavaScript 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004 baaad for money management! and other stuff that requires exact precision.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GREAT $.money class the does almost everything you could ever want from money in the ku4js-kernel library. You can find the documentation [here](http://kodmunki.github.io/ku4js-kernel/#money). Have fun! :{)}

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for something to handle money in node.js and came across this question, and then found esmoney which is a straightforward money calculator.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-money